# Filter by sender Outlook OData web service api

Tags: json, web-services, outlook, odata, outlook-web-app

I am trying to filter my Outlook 365 inbox by sender address. Looking at the OData spec I would have throught it would involve querying a complex type as such

https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Folders('Inbox')/Messages?$filter=From/Address eq 'some@address.com'.

Unfortunately this returns The property 'Address' is invalid.

I can confirm I can access the data

Looking a the JSON if I just query the inbox I see an e-mail

...

```
"From": {

    "Name": "Some One",
    "Address": "some@address.com"

},
```

...

any help with the query string would be greatly appreciated

(p.s. I have dummied the address)

Comment: The query is ok, following the protocol. But it seems that outlook service does not support filter by property of complex type....

Comment: seems like a fairly fundamental piece of functionality that an API would expose. Thanks for checking...

Answer (score 0):

I can repro your failure and from the stacktrace, it should be the service issue. ODatalib can support filter of complex type (you can check http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/PersonDetails?$filter=Address/City eq 'Boise'), but **the exchange service does not**.

```
"stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.ODataFilterConverter.GetEntityProperty(QueryNode queryNode)\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.EwsFilterConverter.ConvertFilterNode(QueryNode queryNode)\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.EwsQueryAdapter.GetRestriction()\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.MessageProvider.Find(String parentFolderId, MessageQueryAdapter queryAdapter)\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.FindMessagesCommand.InternalExecute()\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.ODataCommand`2.Execute()\r\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.ODataTask.Execute(TimeSpan queueAndDelayTime, TimeSpan totalTime)"
```

Comment: Does anybody know if they plan to improve.replace this interface. Seems to be a long way off the competition

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Folders('Inbox')/Messages?$filter=From/EmailAddress/Address eq 'some@address.com'.
```